# Static Map positioning

Tags: html, css

I need a some help with positioning a static Google Maps map.

There are two problems:

1. Having the static map on the same level/line as the writing, the writing on the left and the map on the right
2. Keeping the footer on the bottom of the page

**[CodePen DEMO](http://codepen.io/Petarg/pen/FiAHq)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li class="location"><a href="#">Location</a>

        </li>
        <li class="itinerary"><a href="#">Itinerary</a>

        </li>
        <li class="photos"><a href="#">Howard & Mary</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<h1>Location</h1>

<p class="grid">USS NORTH CAROLINA
    <br/>Address: 1 Battleship Rd NE, Wilmington, NC 28401, United States Telephone: + 1 910-251-5797 wesbite: <a href="http://www.battleshipnc.com/Visit/Directions">www.battleshipnc.com/</a>

</p>
<div class="map">
    <p class="static_map">
        <img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?parameters?key=AIzaSyDM-P7a6oHU7e-guJpKQPADlGPtX1_iPBU&size=400x300&sensor=false&markers=1+Battleship+Rd,+Wilmington,+North+Carolina+28401" alt+ "1 Battleship Rd, Wilmington, North Carolina 28401"/>
    </p>
</div>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https: //maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDM-P7a6oHU7e-guJpKQPADlGPtX1_iPBU&sensor=false"></script>
<footer class="main-footer">
        <h1 class="tri">All donations & proceeds will go towards <a href="http://www.dare2tri.org/" class="dare">Dare 2 Tri</a></h1>

</footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-image: url("http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/1985611/2/stock-photo-1985611-uss-north-carolina.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #0051c2;
    font-size: 80px;
}
.grid {
    color: #0051c2;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 45%;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.map {
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: right;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    height: 175px;
    width: 1100px;  
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.8;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 0;

}
.main-footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-align: center;

}
.tri {
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;

}
ul.nav {
    display: inline;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: auto;
}
ul.nav li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

ul.nav li.home {
    padding: 35px 15px;
    margin: 20px;
    top: 15px;
    font-weight: 100;
    height: 55px;
    width: 130px;
    font-size: 40px;
}
ul.nav li.home:hover {
        background-color: #0051c2;
        border-radius: 8px;
}
ul.nav li.location {
    padding: 35px 15px;
    margin: 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
    top: 15px;
    height: 55px;
    width: 180px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 40px;

}
ul.nav li.location:hover {
    background-color: #0051c2;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
ul.nav li.itinerary {
    padding: 35px 15px;
    margin: 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
    height: 55px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 40px;
}
ul.nav li.itinerary:hover {
    background-color: #0051c2;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
ul.nav li.photos {
    padding: 35px 15px;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border: 0;
    font-weight: 120;
    height: 55px;
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 40px;
}
ul.nav li.photos:hover {
    background-color: #0051c2;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
ul.nav li a {
    color: #faf3bc;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Please don't circumvent the rules; include your actual code in the post if you're going to be including a link to a codepen or similar site.

Comment: Okay. But can you help with the problems? Thank you :) cheers bud

Answer (score 0):

**First Issue: Aligning address with map**

Make your 'grid' `p` into a `div` and add `float:left` to your `.grid` CSS.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kwJcE

**Second Issue: Sticky Footer**

Duplicate question, see here: [Make footer stick to bottom of page correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3443646/1045794)

Direct link: ["A CSS Sticky Footer that just works"](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

**Bonus Third Issue: Terrible Design**

I would never tell anyone they are learning 'wrong' but check out grid systems/frameworks, especially responsive grid systems. It will help you build faster with a better aesthetic.